# Are DBA certification questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Not exactly a technical question, but certainly DBA-relevant. Are cert questions acceptable for the site?

Comment: Can we get an example before we get a ruling?

Comment: Well NDA precludes discussing exam content, but I'm wondering for example re: the new SQL 2012 exams if anyone has sat them yet, are they adaptive or standard, length, are they friggin hard lol. Stuff like that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Well NDA precludes discussing exam content, but I'm wondering for example re: the new SQL 2012 exams if anyone has sat them yet, are they adaptive or standard, length, are they friggin hard lol. Stuff like that

So let's take this in parts:

> NDA precludes discussing exam content

Then no, we can't discuss DBA Certification questions

> wondering if anyone has sat them yet, are they adaptive or standard, length, are they hard

This is better suited to the [third place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy) and I'm sure the chaps and gals in [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) would enjoy the dickens out of discussing the exams, if they've taken any.

To be quite a bit more succinct: Those questions, while well-intentioned as objective, are still somewhat subjectively answered (levels of difficulty always are, by their very nature, subjective), and are likely to change over the course of time, as well as potentially violating NDAs, which we don't need to condone here.

Comment: I'd agree. Cert/exam discussions are more relevant for chat (though violating NDA, while less visible, is no more acceptable there).

Comment: It's been established that NDAs are the poster's problem, not the site's

Comment: @BenBrocka you have prior meta on that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488/166936 Basically if someone freaks out they have to talk to SE.

Comment: I agree with this. In fact, DBA.SE would just become a DBA Certification BrainDump, which are always frozen-in-time and unreliable. The questions and answers already present in DBA.SE bears the marks of both knowledge and years of hands-on experience and it should stay that way.